Capturing page-generated video/audio with Selenium
I want to use Selenium to test a web-based video player. I want to capture the video and audio that ends up actually being displayed in the <video> element on the page, and save that stream (possibly re-encoded) to a file. Then I can do things like diff each frame against the full resolution source material and measure how much quality loss there is end to end.
I can't just inspect the video sources in the DOM and verify that they are what they should be; the page does a lot of complicated logic to dynamically paste together blobs, and I want to end-to-end black-box test it to make sure that the user actually is seeing the stream I want, or a close enough approximation.
I would prefer not to capture the entire page, just the video (i.e. whatever Firefox would suck out into its picture-in-picture display). If necessary, I can put the video into full-screen mode and use a recording of the entire page, if there is a way to get it.
Does Selenium have the necessary hooks into video rendering to do this? If so, how would I use them?

I think there's a docker image of a grid node that uses FFMpeg to record video of the entire session.  You could do something similar.  Diffing each frame is a bit much though... you're going to have different resolutions, different GPUs, etc... this would only record the display of.  Seems more sensible just to download and compare the file(s) and/or validate the src.  Some video players will also have built-in DRM stuff to defeat capture.
